# MSTest inside a Console Application

Tags: c#, mstest, console-application

I was trying to get some tests running inside a console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; // this doesn't work
```

The error I'm getting is:

The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Yet it all works in a seperate test project:
[image]

**Question:**  What is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the target framework of the ConsoleApplication to be `.Net Framework 4` (**NOT** `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`)

> If you are targeting the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot
>   reference an assembly that is not in
>   the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
>   Instead you must target the .NET
>   Framework 4.

You can't reference `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramewor`, because it is not part of the client profile framework.

*EDIT: Sorry, you have that already ...*

You need the reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` in your console application.

You can add it from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies`

The default Visual Studio Test project has this reference by default...

Comment: I also had to add in <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids> into the csproj to get the test runner to recognise this assembly.  http://www.bryancook.net/2009/12/manually-creating-ms-test-project.html

Comment: Have just found out that the console app doesn't run when these GUID's are in there.. it just fires up the test runner.  Going to a seperate project for testing I think.. this was for fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can create test project from visual studio and change the project output type from class library to console application.

Regards
Aseem Bansal